# Visualforce Page shall open standard page and redirect after save

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex

i have a Visualforce Page with a list of contacts and a button in it.

With the button i want to open a standard 'create New Contact' Page, fill in the required fields and return to my Visualforce Page, updating the list with the new contact.

I have absolutly no clue how to do that. 
When i create a PageReference or a 'window.open' via JS, i get the Create-Contact page and can pass attributes to this page, but i cannot return to my VF page.

Background: I used the Quick Create function but this function is a pain in the a**. Therefore i tried to create a new Contact via the standard page.

Answer (score 0):

While opening the create new contact page, pass a parameter called **retURL** to it with value as URL Encoded link to your visualforce page. Standard pages redirect to retURL after their action completes.

```
https://XXX.salesforce.com/XXX/e?retURL=<URL_ENCODED_LINK_TO_YOUR_PAGE>
```